# JQuery Overlay does not auto close on Flowplayer video end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay, flowplayer

Hey guys, I am using both Flowplayer and Jquery Tools Overlay. I have my overlay to display when they click a link. The overlay displays correctly and the video auto-starts as it should but when it ends, I was trying to call the overlay's close function to close it out. Here is my div for the overlay.

```
<script> 
    var player = $f("player", "images/flowplayer-3.1.5.swf",  { 

        // default configuration for a clip 
        clip: conf.defaults

    });

</script>
```

This is using a config js file that I set here:

```
var conf = {

 // default clip configuration
 defaults: {

  autoPlay: true,
  autoBuffering: true,

  // functions are also supported
  onBegin: function() {

   // make controlbar visible in 4000 seconds
   this.getControls().fadeIn(4000);
  },

  onFinish: function() {        // set an event handler in the configuration 
         var b = $("#movie").overlay({oneInstance: false, api: true});
   b.close();
   this.unload();
     }, 

 }
}
```

The problem is when the video ends, it creates the variable "b" but the close function does nothing. I checked in firebug and the variable has the close function open to it. Is there perhaps another way to forcefully close an overlay on it's own?

Answer (score 0):

The 'b' variable is targeting the overlay, but the "this.unload()" is the critical line to the close and it looks correct to me. You do have an extra comma after the onFinish function. Could that be all it is?

```
this.unload(); },
```

should be

```
this.unload(); }
```

Comment: This didn't work. I have the following sample
flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
                // when playback is finished we are performing unload.
                onFinish: function () {
                    this.unload();
                    alert('finish');
                }
            });